# image overflow effect using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if anybody could help me through this:
[Take a look at this Gif please](https://media.giphy.com/media/TIiEiLu7lycVie2KIk/giphy.gif)
As you can see the images overflow each other on scroll!

So how can I use this kind of effect for my images?
Is there any tutorial link or plugin?

Here is my code so far (html and css):

```css
.gallery-img-parent {
    max-height: 200px;
    padding-top: 32px;
    position: relative;
}

.gallery-img-double {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 84px !important;
}

.gallery-double-child {
    position: relative;
}

.gallery-img-parent > a, .gallery-img-parent > .gallery-double {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.gallery-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.gallery-img, .gallery-img-double {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="menu-parent container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="container gallery-container">
                <div class="row justify-content-center gallery-img-parent">
                    <a class="col-6" href="#" id="img1">
                        <img class="gallery-img" src="http://placehold.it/1/acd373">
                    </a>
                    <a class="col-3" href="#" id="img2">
                        <img class="gallery-img" src="http://placehold.it/1/2b3a5c">
                        
                    </a>
                    <a class="col-3" href="#" id="img3">
                        <img class="gallery-img" src="http://placehold.it/1/003a35">
                       
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center gallery-img-parent">
                    <div class="col-3 gallery-double">
                        <a href="#" id="img4" class="gallery-double-child">
                            <img class="gallery-img-double" src="http://placehold.it/1/2b3a5c">
                            
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" id="img5" class="gallery-double-child">
                            <img class="gallery-img-double" src="http://placehold.it/1/1a202e">
                            
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <a class="col-6" href="#" id="img6">
                        <img class="gallery-img" src="http://placehold.it/1/acd373">
                        
                    </a>
                    <a class="col-3" href="#" id="img7">
                        <img class="gallery-img" src="http://placehold.it/1/003a35">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your time ♥ any respond is welcome...

Comment: I think its some sort of paralax effect. Take a look at this demo (http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/). On half of the page you kinda see the effect your looking for.

Comment: https://blog.trackduck.com/2015/06/25/15-captivating-parallax-effects-from-codepen/ and scroll (or `ctr+f`) to "‘Root element’ Parallax Technique"

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks i will try it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea for you:
You will have 4 or more master div, which have different scroll speed, the master divs will overlay on each other. The photos will be populated on each div. The vertical margin between each row will depend on the scroll speed.
Now on your scroll, you will adjust the margin-top/position of each div by its speed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I think your idea is very useful !